# NAPTでは、ポート番号が枯渇した場合どのようなことが起こり、その対策はありますか？

Tags: network

NAPTはIPアドレスの他にポート番号を割り当てて、１つの内部グローバルIPアドレスを複数のホストから使えるようにしたものだと知りました

ポート番号の数にも上限（1024-65535）がありますが、内部グローバルIPアドレスが少ない場合、これによって16ビット以上のホスト部をもつ内部ネットワークとNAPTが接続されているとき内部グローバルIPアドレスを割り当てられない、かつポート番号も枯渇している状況になると思います。

この際に起こることは通常のNATで内部グローバルIPアドレスが足りない場合と同様でしょうか？
またこの問題に対する対応策はありますか？

Comment: 「１つの内部グローバルIPアドレス」→「１つの外部グローバルIPアドレス」と読み替えて良いものでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

何が起きるかは装置次第で、黙って廃棄されるかもしれないし、ICMP host unreachableが帰るかもしれないし、TCPであればRSTが帰ってくるかもしれません。

対応策としては、(ポートは増やせないので)NATに使うアドレスを増やすか、NATされる通信を減らすかです。後者は例えばプロキシサーバを用意することが考えられます。

対応策というか、大抵はまずプロキシサーバありきなので、NATが問題になることはあまりないのですが。

Comment: プロキシサーバを用意する方法は、ポート番号の枯渇の問題に対しては、IPアドレスの追加(≒NAT装置の追加)と同じ対策のように見えます。いかがでしょうか?

Comment: このような場合のプロキシサーバはDMZに置くのでNATしません。あと、IPアドレスの追加はたいてい単に設定だけのはなしです。(I/Fへ割り当てられたアドレスでしかNATできない家庭用ルータでは装置を増やすしかないですが)